# How do I file my US Federal Tax Return from India given that mail is blocked due to COVID?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Currently, I am in India and I have to file my US Federal tax return by July 15, 2020. However, the postal service from India to USA has completely been blocked due to Covid-19. I am seriously puzzled about the situation. Please suggest any means to resolve it.

Comment: Is online filing not an option?

Comment: US taxes can be filed online using links available at https://www.irs.gov/filing/free-file-do-your-federal-taxes-for-free .  The lower link ("income above $69000") has no income restriction; it is only labeled such in contrast to the first link.  Not a full answer as (1) I don't know if it is geo-restricted in any way (2) most, but not all forms are available; if your taxes are complex it may not work, and (3) you may still need a US based bank account to pay balance due or receive refund due electronically, rather than via the postal service.

Comment: Even if you can't file your full return online, you should be able to request an extension of time to file: https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/extension-of-time-to-file-your-tax-return  If you absolutely have to file a paper return, I think the IRS uses the date the return is postmarked.  (Before filing online became common, long lines at post offices were common on the last day.)  So if the Indian Post Office postmarks mail with the date you give it to them, you should be ok even if it sits in their office for weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it corresponds to your facts on the ground, but the US Postal Service seems to think that [some mail is flowing from India](https://about.usps.com/newsroom/service-alerts/international/india.htm):

> 5-27-20
>
> India Post advises a lockdown due to COVID-19 has been extended until May 31. Limited domestic mail exchanges continue in order to provide essential services. However, with the availability of certain cargo and evacuation flights, outbound express mail and international tracked packet services have resumed. All offices of exchange and airmail units are functional; however India Post cannot guarantee service delivery.

If this is not an option, consider private international shipping services like FedEx, UPS, and DHL, which can deliver to the IRS.